# KMS activation without DNS

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, hosts-file, kms

I'm loading a small sized isolated lab with Windows 7 and Office 2013. There are enough hosts to use KMS. In addition the lab does not have DNS as a service available, every host will use a static hosts file. The lab environment will not have access to the internet.

Is there a way to setup the hosts file to allow Office 2013 and Windows 7 to activate against the respective KMS servers?

Comment: How many hosts?  Why not add a DNS server?  Sounds like an unnecessarily laborious approach.

Comment: This is a case of "here is the designed system, make it work." But, its ~25 hosts in a disconnected network.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the following:

```
cscript %systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs /skms <ip address of kms server>  
cscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ospp.vbs" /sethst:<ip address of kms server>
```

Comment: I am afraid that it is `/skms <ip>` not `/skms:<ip>`. MS documentation says, `slmgr.vbs /skms <value>:<port>`